# CNN with LSTM-Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have implemented a CNN with an LSTM layer. My input consists of four images. The images were transformed into a tensor by feature extraction. The input shape is (4,256,256,3).

The following is the structure of my model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'),input_shape = (4,256,256,3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))


model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4,4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))


model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh'))# finalize with standard Dense, Dropout...
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=['MSE'])
history = model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=4, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2, validation_data=(X,Y))
```

My problem is that my model predicts the same values for all inputs.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide info what values you have in Y. Are these some labels or some real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with a classification problem specifically binary classification, then using sigmoid activation instead softmax And MSE loss is not a good choice for binary classification.

Answer (score 0):

you use the same data for training and validation. this kills the whole point of validation. Perhaps the mistake lies in this. Try to split the data, or apply cross validation.

Also, the application of the relu activation function to the last layer in combination with the mse error looks strange. At least the real can give an unlimited result, and the data should be normalized.

I hope this will help you